# Is there a way to "load" the browser but not display anything? CefSharp

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp

I'm trying to create a program that will basically include several browser instances (in order not to share cache) and on each browser instance, I need to open a webpage and stay on it.

However, as you might assume, amount of RAM that it would consume is huge, and it would also pressure CPU too much. My idea is basically disabling all the "looks" and just run it as some kind of background process. Basically, simulate the open browser but not displaying anything, thus saving both RAM and CPU.

I don't need to see what's happening in these browser instance, I just need them to be open and run some Javascript on start. At the moment, I have the program, but all of the browser instances are displayed and it takes too much resources. I need to be able to run 50-60 of browser instances.

I'm developing it in .Net and C#, alongside CefSharp (chromium browser)

Does anyone have any suggestions what can I do on this matter?

Comment: Have a look at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Comment: You can use CefSharp.Offscreen and tell the browser it's hidden so it doesn't render frames

Comment: 'I need to be able to run 50-60 of browser instances' => I really think you need to step back and consider this.  It really sounds like an X-Y issue.  You say you just need them to run some Javascript on start and stay open, but if they are _only_ running some Javascript on start what purpose are they fulfilling staying open?

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for! I'll try it out

@tolanj I need to stay on those pages, in order to have active socket connection there. Only that way, server will count me as "connected"

Comment: If the requirements are as you say, have a pool of n browsers connecting through a _nearly-transparent proxy_.  Have the proxy keep alive the socket connection after the browser has finished.  I do find it hard to understand why you would need 50-60 open and apparently permanently-inactive connections.

Comment: @tolanj I'm not able to change anything on the server I'm connecting to. I have benefit of basically 50-60 different users being connected to the socket, so I need to keep the connection alive until I don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THanks everyone for suggestions! If anyone need something like this, you can use headless version of cefSharp browser. It works pretty much the same for me.